# Getting a blob with cljs-ajax

Tags: ajax, clojurescript, cljs-ajax

I am trying to read my ajax response as a blob. 
The response is present, and can be read with

```
:response-format ajax.edn/edn-read
```

for example, but it is in fact an image and I need it as a blob to serve as an `<img src=''` url. (created with `createObjectURL`)

I'm not finding an example anywhere, I guess it should be something in the line of :

```
:response-format {:content-type: "image/jpeg" :read :body :type :blob}
```

but that's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to put it that way:

```
(ns browser
  (:require
[ajax.protocols :refer [-body]]


...

:response-format {:content-type "image/png"
                  :type :blob
                  :description "PNG file"
                  :read -body}
```